# js ternary operator: not returning falsy

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

stepping through with a breakpoint at second `for...in` with `if (map[t[i]])`, expected `false` but actual is `true`. can someone help explain why this occurs?

```
const s = 'rat',
  t = 'car';

const isAnagram = (s, t) => {
  if (s.length !== t.length) {
    return false;
  }

  const map = {};

  for (let i in s) {
    map[s[i]] ? map[s[i]]++ : (map[s[i]] = 1);
  }

  for (let i in t) {
    // this works
    // if (map[t[i]]) {
    //   map[t[i]]--;
    // } else {
    //   return false;
    // }

    // this doesn't ?¿?¿
    map[t[i]] ? map[t[i]]-- : false;
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(isAnagram(s, t)); // false
```

Comment: this `map[s[i]] ? map[s[i]]++ : map[s[i]] = 1;` is awakward and bad practise. it is better to explicitly do it: `map[s[i]] = map[s[i]] ? (map[s[i]]+1) : 1;`

Comment: `map[t[i]] ? map[t[i]]++ : false;` doesn't return from the function. It just produces the value `false` but you never use it. It's the same as doing `var a = 1; false; a += 1` for example - the `false` is a statement of no consequence.

Comment: @VLAZ btw i edited to `--` instead of `++`. how would you rewrite this as ternary?

Comment: You cannot `return` as part of a conditional expression. The operator accepts three *expressions* but `return` is a *statement*. It cannot be nested as part of a conditional expression.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks that makes more sense- appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const isAnagram = (s, t) => {
  const [sMap, tMap] = [s, t].map(
    str =>
    str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "").split("").reduce((map, cursor) => {
      map[cursor] = 1 + (map[cursor] ? map[cursor] : 0);
      return map;
    }, {})
  );

  return !Object.keys(sMap).some(prop => sMap[prop] !== tMap[prop]);
}

console.log(isAnagram("me", "hobo")); // false

// all true
console.log(isAnagram("rail safety", "fairy tales"));
console.log(isAnagram("debit card", "bad credit"));
console.log(isAnagram("William Shakespeare", "I am a weakish speller"));
```

Comment: true, but this works assuming `rat` and `tar` are reversals of each other but not for something let's say `anagram` and `nagaram`

Comment: thank you. i misinterpreted the question and I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You could just sort strings, filter whitespaces and compare:

```js
const s = 'rat';
const t = 'tar'
const u = "cat";

isAnagram = (s, t) =>
  [...s].filter(c => c !== ' ').sort().join() === [...t].filter(c => c !== ' ').sort().join()
  
console.log(isAnagram(s, t))
console.log(isAnagram(s, u))
```

Comment: it would be best if you trimmed/filtered out whitespace as well before sorting the letters, so check only the anagram letters not whitespace which is irrelevant for checking anagrams

Comment: You're right @NikosM ! I edited.